# Adding Shortcode to WP (functions.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress and PHP newbie here.

I just want to add the most basic shortcode *directly* into `functions.php` for learning purposes. My shortcode does not work, basically, nothing happens. If I am able to run this simple code, then I will try more complex shortcodes.

```
function hello_world() {
  return 'Hello World!';
}

add_shortcode('helloworld', 'hello_world');
```

In a page, I add `[helloworld]` using the Gutenberg shortcode block. I cannot see any errors on the page or console. Am I missing something fundamental to add shortcodes?

Comment: I tested your code and it works - displays "Hello World!" in the place of the shortcode block. I'm not sure if binding to the init event suggested by Marcello is a better practice, but it works with or without it. Check wp-content/debug.log maybe if php wasn't terminated before for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
function hello_world() {
  return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>';
}

function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('helloworld', 'hello_world');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

In order to execute our register_shortcodes() function, you will tie it to WordPress’ initialization action.

Then try your shortcode with `[helloworld]`

Please let me know if it works

Comment: can you give me more information about it? where did you display the shortcode? does the shortcode display something on the screen?

Comment: It doesn't matter in a page or a post, it is displayed like text: `[helloworld]`. I think I need to dive into the theme. There must be something blocking this simple code.

Comment: I'm assuming that you had the code in function.php. It must work in this way. Have you checked your php error logs